# Running Steam and Streaming on ExaGear Desktop with Pi2

Tags: streaming, games

I've been trying to install Steam on my Rasberry Pi 2 through [ExaGear Desktop](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/), a program that allows x86 apps to run on ARM. I followed the steps here: https://wiki.debian.org/Steam and Steam installs successfully.

Unfortunately when I run steam with `$ steam` it quits while starting.

It doesn't seem like many people have tried this, but I think it could be a good alternative to [NVidia GameStream](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/shield/games/gamestream/) for streaming. I found this one video demonstrating it working [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/364042703860377373/), but it doesn't include any instructions.

The output in the console after downloading the updates is as follows:

```
[2017-03-26 16:57:29] Downloading update (268991 of 268991 KB)...
[2017-03-26 16:57:32] Download Complete.
[2017-03-26 16:57:32] uninstalled manifest found in /home/pi/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2017-03-26 16:57:35] Extracting package... 
[2017-03-26 17:02:17] Installing update...
[2017-03-26 17:02:46] Cleaning up...
[2017-03-26 17:02:47] Update complete, launching...
[2017-03-26 17:02:47] Shutdown Running Steam on debian 8 32-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically 
[2017-03-26 17:05:42] Startup - updater built Mar 22 2017 23:44:00
[2017-03-26 17:05:45] Verifying installation... 
[2017-03-26 17:05:45] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/pi/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2017-03-26 17:05:45] Verification complete
[2017-03-26 17:05:45] Downloading update... 
[2017-03-26 17:05:45] Checking for available updates...
[2017-03-26 17:05:46] Download complete.
[2017-03-26 17:05:46] uninstalled manifest found in /home/pi/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2017-03-26 17:05:48] Extracting package... 
[2017-03-26 17:09:59] Installing update... 
[2017-03-26 17:11:09] Cleaning up...
[2017-03-26 17:11:10] Update complete, launching Steam...
[2017-03-26 17:11:10] Shutdown Restarting Steam by request... Running Steam on debian 8 32-bit STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/pi/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime 
[2017-03-26 17:11:26] Startup - updater built Mar 22 2017 23:44:00
[2017-03-26 17:11:28] Verifying installation...
[2017-03-26 17:11:30] Verification complete
```